# Gamecube too bright with elgato

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

I've recently connected Gamecube on my PC monitor(its quite modern) and the elgato game capture hd to record some games.Everything worked fine,except it is way to bright.
Is it because i connected it to a modern pc monitor or is it because it's connected to the elgato?
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Is it the monitor that's too bright or the video capture?

Comment: The video Capture is allright,but on the monitor its hard to see anything.

Comment: Have you check to see if the monitor itself has any brightness/contrast controls? It may simply be the built in settings are up too high.

Answer (score -2):

Check your gamma settings with your Elgato driver on your PC.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than a solution